# How to prove the following linearized operator is positive?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, schrodinger-operators, perturbation-theory

In $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, let $Q$ be the solution to
\begin{equation}
-\Delta Q+\alpha^2 Q = |Q|^{2\sigma} Q,
\end{equation}
and $Q$ satisfies that it is positive, radial, and exponentially decaying (here we can guarantee the existence and uniquenss of such equation in some restriction), and we say $Q$ is the ground state.

We want to see that the linearized operator $L_- \triangleq -\Delta +\alpha^2 -Q^{2\sigma}$ is positive, i.e. $\left\langle L_- f,f  \right\rangle \ge 0, \; \forall f \in L^2$. But I do not know how to check it. The only hints are as follows:
\begin{equation}
L_- Q=0,
\end{equation}thus $0 \in \sigma(L_-)$, and $Q>0$ is the ground state.

The question is from **Appendix A** in [Michael I. Weinstein: Modulation stability of ground states of nonlinear Schrodinger equations](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0516034).

Comment: Seems like a Rayleigh quotient argument ? Q is the ground state, i.e. eigenfunction corresponding to lowest eigenvalue, which is equal to 0 here since $L_{-}Q=0$. Now apply rayleigh quotient thm to prove positivity.

Comment: $Q$ is the ground state, meaning that $Q$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue equal to the minimum of the spectrum. Since this is $0$ here, this says that $\sigma(L_-)\subseteq [0,\infty)$, which is how being a positive operator is defined.

Comment: @ChristianRemling thank you, but how can I check zero is the minimum of the spectrum, or it is the lowest eigenvalue? I just know $Q$ satisfies the properties I posed in my question above.

Comment: @Tao.Zhou I believe you can look into Ref. [4] in the paper to see why the ground state has lowest eigenvalue. In general, such operators have a unique positive eigenfunction (i.e., all other eigenfunctions must be positive and negative somewhere) and it corresponds to lowest eigenvalue, thats why it is called ground (i.e., lowest) state

Comment: @PiyushGrover ok, I will see something about what you said, thank you very much.

Comment: @Tao.Zhou: As already suggested by Piyush, look up the result that the ground state (= lowest eigenvalue) eigenfunction is positive. Then there can't be other positive eigenfunctions because they wouldn't be orthogonal to each other.